# Prestashop 1.7 get current step in checkout process

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

The PS website we try to configure has to deliver only in a single state from a specific country but has to allow the billing to any country in the world.
For that, I managed to restrict the country to only one and then by code to change the behaviour of the states dropdown with the following code:

```
public function getFormat()
{
    $format = parent::getFormat();
    $format['id_state']->setAvailableValues(
                            [999 =>'CustomState'],
                        );
}
```

The code was placed inside a override of `CustomerAddressFormatterCore` but using it like this will also restrict the billing states to only one.
Now, we try to capture the steps from the checkout process and up to now without any success

I saw that PS 1.7 uses the class `CheckoutProcess` function `public function getCurrentStep()`
Anyone knows how to use that inside an override of the `CustomerAddressFormatterCore`?
Is that the correct approach? Is there any other better solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear distinction saying that Address X is the billing one, and Address Y is the shipping one, and I'm afraid checking if you're in the context of the checkout step won't help you.

Most of the time, one address is used for both the shipping and the invoice. If someone wants to edit a particular address, you will have information about it in the `$_GET` params. Unless you're using a third-party OPC module?